# Number validation using regular expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to apply a validation for input field. I thought regular expression might be a cleaner approach. I am interested to know if I can achieve a validation with the following rules in regular expression

1. Rule one - Only numbers
2. Rule two - Not less than 62
3. Rule three - Not more than 123
4. Rule four - If the number is between 62 and 100, can have a one point decimal (eg: 65.4)
5. Any number over 100 cannot have any decimal points

Here is what i have got so far

```
\b([6-9][2-9]|1[01][0-9]|12[0-3])\b
```

Comment: Regexes detect text patterns. They don't know about numeric values. Whatever language you're using, chances are it will be better to just use that language to check the numeric value (e.g. `!(n < 62)`).  Using a regex to check a numeric value is like stirring a can of paint with a screwdriver. You can do it, but there are better tools for the job that will leave less mess.

Comment: you have a problem, you decide to use regex to solve it, now you have 2 problems. All joking aside this is not a good regex use case. Read the string in, check its numeric, your language will have support for that, then check range

Comment: Thank you guys, I have started to go down that paths anyways. Writing the validation in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

That's not so bad. You could test with the following regular expression.

```
^(?:(?:6[2-9]|[7-9]\d|100)(?:\.\d)?|10[1-9]|11\d|12[013])$
```

This expression does not use any advanced features so it should work with most every regex engine.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7mxYoO/1)

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^                       # match beginning of string
(?:                     # begin a non-capture group
  (?:                   # begin a non-capture group
    6[2-9]|[7-9]\d|100  # match '62'-'100'
  )                     # end non-capture group
  (?:\.\d)?             # optionally match a period followed by a digit
|                       # or
  10[1-9]|11\d|12[013]  # match '101'-'123'
)                       # end non-capture group
$                       # match end of string
```